# How to show rows with data which are not equal?

Tags: pandas

I have two tables

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])   
                   
print(df1.equals(df2))
```

I want to compare them. I want the same result if I would use function `df.compare(df1)` or at least something close to it. Can't use above fnction as my complier states that `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'compare'`

Answer (score 1):

**First approach:**

Let's compare value by value:

```
In [1183]: eq_df = df1.eq(df2)

In [1196]: eq_df
Out[1200]: 
      a     b      c
0  True  True  False
1  True  True   True
2  True  True   True
```

Then let's reduce it down to see which rows are equal for all columns

```
from functools import reduce
In [1285]: eq_ser = reduce(np.logical_and, (eq_df[c] for c in eq_df.columns))

In [1288]: eq_ser
Out[1293]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Now we can print out the rows which are not equal

```
In [1310]: df1[~eq_ser]
Out[1315]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  4

In [1316]: df2[~eq_ser]
Out[1316]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

**Second approach:**

```
def diff_dataframes(
    df1, df2, compare_cols=None
) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
    """
    Given two dataframes and column(s) to compare, return three dataframes with rows:
    - common between the two dataframes
    - found only in the left dataframe
    - found only in the right dataframe
    """
    df1 = df1.fillna(pd.NA)
    df = df1.merge(df2.fillna(pd.NA), how="outer", on=compare_cols, indicator=True)

    df_both = df.loc[df["_merge"] == "both"].drop(columns="_merge")
    df_left = df.loc[df["_merge"] == "left_only"].drop(columns="_merge")
    df_right = df.loc[df["_merge"] == "right_only"].drop(columns="_merge")

    tup = namedtuple("df_diff", ["common", "left", "right"])
    return tup(df_both, df_left, df_right)
```

Usage:

```
In [1366]: b, l, r = diff_dataframes(df1, df2)

In [1371]: l
Out[1371]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  4

In [1372]: r
Out[1372]: 
   a  b  c
3  1  2  3
```

**Third approach:**

```
In [1440]: eq_ser = df1.eq(df2).sum(axis=1).eq(len(df1.columns))
```

Comment: But if I have a huge dataframe with many columns and rows, I should go through every column?

Comment: I think you will have to. Check the different approaches and benchmark them.